# SharePoint Pages generating random URL on publish

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, modern-pages, newsfeed

Users are creating site pages below a site. The content of the page will usually be a daily news update so users are creating a copy of the previous days page and then editing the content and name of this new page.

They are then saving the page and pressing publish. This brings up the side pane
"Help Others find your page" at the bottom of this it displays the page address. However SharePoint has not used the page title as the page address but generated a random string of characters instead.

eg: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/PublicComms/SitePages/9m488nde.aspx

They then receive the error message:

"Couldn't add to navigation We published your page, but couldn't add it to navigation. Please try adding it directly. First copy the link to your page, and then click Edit in the navigation"

[image]

After this happens we are unable to find the newly published page within the site pages folder at all.

If we try to access the page using the random string url it has generated we get the error "This site can't be reached"

The only was we can ever find the page is by the fact that it is pulled into the news webpart. From here you can click onto the page.

This issue is happening very sporadically and I am finding it difficult to troubleshoot because of this. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to resolve the problem?

Edit: confirmed with the users that this issue only happens when copying the page

Second Edit: This issue is also happening when users are creating a new page from scratch.

Edit 3 27/11: I have noticed that when I received the couldn't add to navigation error I am getting this error within the dev console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you still see this error if you create a new post directly without creating a copy of another one?

I’m not able to reproduce this issue in my test environment. Everything works fine in both team site and communication site.
But I did run into another “unexpected error” if I enter another username in the people picker in the Title area or just leave it empty when publishing the page.

[image]

I would suggest you open a service request with Microsoft 365 team via *Microsoft 365 admin center > Support > New service request* to get dedicated help and let the team look into it.

Comment: I will ask the users to create the post directly to see if they are able to recreate the error this way. Unfortunately I have had a couple tickets open with Microsoft 365 about this issue, but it is very hard for them to troubleshoot due to it's sporadic nature so they have been archived.

Comment: Just checked with the users and this only occurs on copy of the page

Comment: @Sam OK. Do you see this issue in another site?

Comment: Yes, the user has reported this issue happening on several site

Comment: @Sam One more suggestion: If you cannot decide if this is a service side issue or something wrong with the page, consider removing the web parts/sections on the page one by one from one of the issued pages, see if the user will get rid of the error somehow.